# LinkedIn API for retrieving messages?

Tags: linkedin-api

Previously Linkedin v1 have Api for retrieving messages from linkedin Inbox, now its deprecated . What is the v2 Linkedin Api  for retreiving messages from inbox.

Answer (score -1):

`api.linkedin.com`
That the new link for their api

Comment: it give's link not found message